# What does the output "shell 514/tcp cmd no passwords used" mean?

Tags: security, port

I ran the command `cat /etc/services` and got a long out of ports. Then I saw this one and i googled what is its purpose but I still don't get it. What does "cmd" mean here and why does it say "no passwords used"?

The line:

```
shell       514/tcp     cmd     # no passwords used
```

Comment: Did you check `man services`? Also, the line wasn't t really presented in exactly that way, was it? There's a `#` missing.  Could you also say something about why you singled out _this_ particular line and not some other service's line?

Comment: I checked `man services` now so that means that cmd and no passwords used belongs to aliases which again i don't fully understand. And yes there is a # missing. I singled it out because i associated "cmd" with Windows and I thought the "not passwords used"  part looked concerning. Im sure if I look long enough in the list I will freak out on more ports

Comment: Why are port/service definitions in /etc/services freaking you out?  It is purely informative, it has little impact on running services on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Port 514 is sometimes used for Remote Shell, a command called rsh. It is for remote control of a server but by default does not provide for encryption or passwords. Almost like telnet but with a shell around it.

It is legacy software that most people do not use. Instead, ssh is the secure (remote) shell that everyone uses.